# What is the most parsimonious model of natural number computation?

Tags: soft-question, computability

Let's define a model of natural number computation to consist of three functions

$E:\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

$T:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

$D:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$

with the property that for all computable functions $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$,

$\exists p \in \mathbb{N}: \forall x \in \mathbb{N}: D(T^*(E(p,x)) = f(x)$

The idea is that for every computable function $f$ there is a program $p$, which we can Encode along with any input $x$, then pass that to a Transform that we iterate until it reaches a fixed point.  Then we Decode that fixed point to get $f(x)$.

We are going to want $E$, $T$, $D$ to all be polynomial-time computable, some bounds on the growth of $T$ to preserve polynomial-time equivalence, and perhaps some other conditions.

My question is, what is the simplest universal machine that can be described in these terms?

I believe that it is possible to have

$E(p,x) = 2^p \cdot (2 \cdot x + 1)$

$D(y) = \frac{y - 1}{2}$

and

$T(2 \cdot n + 1) = 2 \cdot n + 1$

but the full definition of $T$ becomes very complicated.  The input number is considered as a binary Turing machine tape, and $p$ as an encoding of the state transition table of a Turing machine, along with its current state and position on the tape.  Then $T$ is defined to iterate that machine one step and return the new (even) encoding, or else if it is in a halting state, divide out all powers of $2$.  $T$'s implementation can be improved slightly at the expense of $E$, by instead defining $E(p, x) = 2^{2^p} \cdot (2 \cdot x + 1)$.  Then an intermediate state can be represented as $2^{2^p \cdot (2 \cdot s + 1)} \cdot (2 \cdot x + 1)$ where $s$ is the tape head position.  That makes it easy to describe the decoding and re-encoding of the tape position inside the definition of $T$, but the problem of encoding and iterating a state transition table remains.

I know other ways of setting this up so that $T$ is relatively simple but $E$ and $D$ have longer specifications.  For example, I understand Conway proved $T$ can be a Collatz-type function.  Also it may be possible to describe [Rule 110](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110) this way.  Another example that seems more balanced is SKI combinator calculus or [Jot](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Jot), depending on what reduction step function and what kind of Church numerals we choose.

Intuitively, there is a certain amount of necessary complexity involved in defining a universal machine so the best we can do is to shift it around between these functions.  But I am not convinced that is true.  So I am wondering, is there is some simpler definition of $T$ that is universal given $E(p,x) = 2^p \cdot (2 \cdot x + 1)$ and $D(y) = \frac{y - 1}{2}$, or some other Encoder and Decoder with very short definitions, or where $E(p,x) = E_p(p) \cdot E_x(x)$ for some other functions $E_p$ and $E_x$?

Answer (score 4):

> Intuitively, there is a certain amount of necessary complexity involved in defining a universal machine so $\color{blue}{\text{the best we can do is to shift it around between these functions}}$.

That latter part is demonstrably false, due to the fact that your three functions $(E,T,D)$ can all be quite simple while concentrating the "complexity" in yet another place, viz., the program-numbering function. A good example of this is Conway's universal FRACTRAN program called POLYGAME:

$U=\left(\frac{583}{559}\, \frac{629}{551}\, \frac{437}{527}\, \frac{82}{517}\, \frac{615}{329}\, \frac{371}{129}\, \frac{1}{115}\, \frac{53}{86}\, \frac{43}{53}\, \frac{23}{47}\, \frac{341}{46}\, \frac{41}{43}\, \frac{47}{41}\, \frac{29}{37}\, \frac{37}{31}\, \frac{299}{29}\, \frac{47}{23}\, \frac{161}{15}\, \frac{527}{19}\, \frac{159}{7}\, \frac{1}{17}\, \frac{1}{13}\, \frac{1}{3}\right).$

Here $E(p,x)=p\,2^{2^x}$, $D(y)=\log_2\log_2 y $, and $T(n)=nf,$ where $f$ is the leftmost fraction in $U$ for which $nf$ is an integer (taking $f=1,$ i.e. $T(n)=n,$ if there is no such fraction). Practically all of the "complexity" is now involved in determining a number $p$ that codes a desired program.

A program-number for computing the $x$th digit of $\pi$, for example, is
$$p_\pi=3^{A}\cdot 5^{2^{89\cdot101!}+2^{90\cdot101!}}\cdot 17^{101!-1}\cdot 23
$$
where 
$$A=2^{100!}+\sum_{i=1}^{38}2^{f_i\cdot101^{i}\cdot100!}+2^{101^{39}\cdot100!}
$$
and $f_i$ is the $i$th fraction in the following list:
$$\left(\frac{365}{46}\, \frac{29}{161}\, \frac{79}{575}\, \frac{7}{451}\, \frac{3159}{413}\, \frac{83}{497}\, \frac{473}{371}\, \frac{638}{355}\, \frac{434}{335}\, \frac{89}{235}\, \frac{17}{209}\, \frac{79}{122}\, \frac{31}{183}\, \frac{41}{115}\, \frac{517}{89}\, \frac{111}{83}\, \frac{305}{79}\, \frac{23}{73}\, \frac{73}{71}\, \frac{61}{67}\, \frac{37}{61}\, \frac{19}{59}\, \frac{89}{57}\, \frac{41}{53}\, \frac{883}{47}\, \frac{53}{43}\, \frac{86}{41}\, \frac{13}{38}\, \frac{23}{37}\, \frac{67}{31}\, \frac{71}{29}\, \frac{83}{19}\, \frac{475}{17}\, \frac{59}{13}\, \frac{41}{3}\, \frac{1}{7}\, \frac{1}{11}\, \frac{1}{1024}\right).$$

Obviously, the "complexity" being discussed here relates only to the "parsimony of definition", as distinct from computational complexity, etc.

For sources, see [this googology wiki entry](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/FRACTRAN_catalogue_numbers).

Comment: This is a great answer but there is a technicality, $E(p,x)$ is not computable in time polynomial in $\log(x)$.  I think this matters because if we were to implement a polynomial-time algorithm this way on a real computer, representing numbers in binary, it would not actually run in polynomial time because the encoding step takes too long.  Maybe this can be worked around with a different representation of the internal state (odd part paired with a recursive decomposition of powers of $2$?), fixing the problem but adding another source of definitional complexity.